# No data in Neptune after bulk load

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune

After loading a lot of data into the Neptune from S3, I cannot see any vertices in the database. Here is my loader status:

```json
curl -G 'https://**.amazonaws.com:8182/loader/**?details=true&errors=true'
^[[A{
    "status" : "200 OK",
    "payload" : {
        "feedCount" : [
            {
                "LOAD_FAILED" : 1
            }
        ],
        "overallStatus" : {
            "fullUri" : "s3://**.nt",
            "runNumber" : 1,
            "retryNumber" : 0,
            "status" : "LOAD_FAILED",
            "totalTimeSpent" : 13035,
            "startTime" : 1626033369,
            "totalRecords" : 1745612081,
            "totalDuplicates" : 3580674,
            "parsingErrors" : 22,
            "datatypeMismatchErrors" : 0,
            "insertErrors" : 0
        },
        "failedFeeds" : [
            {
                "fullUri" : "s3://**.nt",
                "runNumber" : 1,
                "retryNumber" : 0,
                "status" : "LOAD_FAILED",
                "totalTimeSpent" : 13032,
                "startTime" : 1626033372,
                "totalRecords" : 1745612081,
                "totalDuplicates" : 3580674,
                "parsingErrors" : 22,
                "datatypeMismatchErrors" : 0,
                "insertErrors" : 0
            }
        ],
        "errors" : {
            "startIndex" : 1,
            "endIndex" : 10,
            "loadId" : "**",
            "errorLogs" : [
                {
                    "errorCode" : "PARSING_ERROR",
                    "errorMessage" : "IRI includes string escapes: '\\92'",
                    "fileName" : "s3://**.nt",
                    "recordNum" : 195142350
                },
                {
                    "errorCode" : "PARSING_ERROR",
                    "errorMessage" : "IRI includes string escapes: '\\92'",
                    "fileName" : "s3://**.nt",
                    "recordNum" : 213781671
                },
                {
                    "errorCode" : "PARSING_ERROR",
                    "errorMessage" : "IRI includes string escapes: '\\92'",
                    "fileName" : "s3://**.nt",
                    "recordNum" : 223606399
                },
                {
                    "errorCode" : "PARSING_ERROR",
                    "errorMessage" : "IRI includes string escapes: '\\92'",
                    "fileName" : "s3://**.nt",
                    "recordNum" : 237802811
                },
                {
                    "errorCode" : "PARSING_ERROR",
                    "errorMessage" : "IRI includes string escapes: '\\92'",
                    "fileName" : "s3://**.nt",
                    "recordNum" : 459805351
                },
                {
                    "errorCode" : "PARSING_ERROR",
                    "errorMessage" : "IRI includes string escapes: '\\92'",
                    "fileName" : "s3://**.nt",
                    "recordNum" : 603488680
                },
                {
                    "errorCode" : "PARSING_ERROR",
                    "errorMessage" : "IRI includes string escapes: '\\92'",
                    "fileName" : "s3://**.nt",
                    "recordNum" : 644623634
                },
                {
                    "errorCode" : "PARSING_ERROR",
                    "errorMessage" : "IRI includes string escapes: '\\92'",
                    "fileName" : "s3://**.nt",
                    "recordNum" : 696970927
                },
                {
                    "errorCode" : "PARSING_ERROR",
                    "errorMessage" : "IRI includes string escapes: '\\92'",
                    "fileName" : "s3://**.nt",
                    "recordNum" : 700557784
                },
                {
                    "errorCode" : "PARSING_ERROR",
                    "errorMessage" : "IRI includes string escapes: '\\92'",
                    "fileName" : "s3://**.nt",
                    "recordNum" : 714098924
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it mentions that I have 22 parsing errors and ~1.7B total records. I can assume as I had set `"failOnError" : "FALSE",` in my request, the database should be all good but 22 items which I'm completely okay with.

At this point, I was sure that database is there but after running a simple query I can see nothing:

```
curl -G "https://**.amazonaws.com:8182?gremlin=g.V().count()"

{"requestId":"**","status":{"message":"","code":200,"attributes":{"@type":"g:Map","@value":[]}},"result":{"data":{"@type":"g:List","@value":[{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":0}]},"meta":{"@type":"g:Map","@value":[]}}}
```

Comment: It looks as if you loaded RDF data but tried to read it back using Gremlin. For RDF data you will need to use SPARQL. What does `SELECT ?s ?p ?o where {?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 1` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you loaded RDF data (N-Triples format). RDF data must be queried using SPARQL with Amazon Neptune. Gremlin can only be used on property graph data (loaded as CSV files using the bulk loader). To verify that you have some data try using a SPARQL query such as:

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o where {?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It's indeed the case that SPARQL interface works! It kinda doesn't make sense, as these should be just querying interfacfe.